# How to use JQuery Datatable with Golang?

Tags: javascript, go, datatables

I am using JQuery Datatable to list the details in my Database. I wrote my server side in Golang. I have my database values stored in a map called `dBdetails` now I want to display the contents of this map using Datables. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert **Map into a Slice** and use it in JQuery.

```
dataValue := reflect.ValueOf(dBdetails)
var valueSlice []string
for key, value := range dataValue.MapKeys() {
    keySlice = append(keySlice, key)
    valueSlice = append(valueSlice, value)
}

log.Println(keySlice, valueSlice)
```

The above code will convert map into slice.